# Error creating cloudformation stackset: Access denied for operation 'CreateLink'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

While following the AWS blogpost on [creating a monitoring account](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudwatch-cross-account-observability/), we are hitting the error:

```
ResourceStatusReason:Resource handler returned message: "Access denied for operation 'CreateLink'." (RequestToken: xxx, HandlerErrorCode: AccessDenied).
```

We are logged into the management account as root user and are using the service-managed permissions option as [documented in the cloud formation user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacksets-getting-started-create.html#stacksets-orgs-associate-stackset-with-org-console) , which states:

> With service-managed permissions, you can deploy stack instances to accounts managed by AWS Organizations in specific Regions. With this model, you don't need to create the necessary IAM roles; StackSets creates the IAM roles on your behalf. You can also enable automatic deployments to accounts that are added to a target organization or organizational unit (OU) in the future. With automatic deployments enabled, StackSets automatically deletes stack instances from an account if it's removed from a target organization or OU.

As we are logged in with Root and managed accounts permissions should be managed automatically, I'm not sure what we are doing wrong.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Did you find a work around?

Answer (score 0):

The error may be in the Cloudformation template that you download in the "Link your source account" section. Check that the link ARN is correct on the following line:

```
    SinkIdentifier: "arn:aws:oam:us-east-1:123456789012:sink/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

The first time I downloaded this template, this line appeared:

```
    SinkIdentifier: "arn:[Object object]:oam:us-east-1:123456789012:sink/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

So I fixed it manually before deploying it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem. The root cause for me was that when [configuring the monitoring account (Step 1)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Unified-Cross-Account-Setup.html#CloudWatch-Unified-Cross-Account-Setup-permissions) I had provided an Organization Path in the format `o-abc123xyz/r-abcd/`. Using just my Organization ID `o-abc123xyz` solved the issue.

While debugging, looking at the CloudTrail event history in the failed source account was helpful to understand which roles CloudFormation was assuming and which specific permissions were missing.

Behind the scenes, the monitoring account configuration creates the following policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": ["oam:CreateLink", "oam:UpdateLink"],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "oam:ResourceTypes": [
                    "AWS::Logs::LogGroup",
                    "AWS::CloudWatch::Metric",
                    "AWS::XRay::Trace",
                    "AWS::ApplicationInsights::Application"
                ]
            },
            "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-abc123xyz"
            }
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

I suspect having a `PrincipalOrgID` value that included an org path was breaking things.